# Adding a row to a named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a named range in Google Sheets (`A1:K14`). All I'm trying to do is add a new row at the bottom of the named range. It seems like an easy task. The named range doesn't expand using this code and I don't get an error message. It does insert a new row outside of the named range, which is not what I'm trying to do. If I change to `insertRowBefore (lastRow)`, the new blank row is inserted and the named range is expanded. I'm teaching myself GAS, so this is probably a simple mistake on my part

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var Range = sheet.setActiveRange(range);
var data = Range.getValues();
Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('DataRange').getNumRows();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertRowAfter(lastRow);
return range;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Adding rows and/or columns to a namedRange**

This function has the defaults setup to add one row.

```
//r is number of rows to add
//c is number of columns to add
function addRowAndColumnsToNamedRange(name,r,c) {
  var name=name||'One';//default name
  var r=r||1;//default number of rows to add
  var c=c||0;//default number columns to add
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var  nrgA=ss.getNamedRanges();
  for(var i=0;i<nrgA.length;i++) {
    if(nrgA[i].getName()==name) {
      var nr=nrgA[i];
      var h=nr.getRange().getHeight();
      var w=nr.getRange().getWidth();
      var sh=nr.getRange().getSheet();
      var row=nr.getRange().getRow();
      var col=nr.getRange().getColumn();
      var rg=sh.getRange(row,col,h+r,w+c);
      ss.setNamedRange(name,rg);
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

[Class NamedRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range)

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thanks for the example and suggestion. I think the  insertRowBefore and InsertRowAfter threw me off. It sounds like they work for inserting rows inside the bounds of the array. It make sense that once you expand the array you'd have to reassign it using the new dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the approach can be to get that `NamedRange` and expand it explicitly.

Something like this:

1. Get that `NamedRange` using [`getNamedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getNamedRanges()) :
2. Set range of that `NamedRange` including new row using [`setRange(range)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range.html#setrangerange)

Comment: One thing you can do with named ranges is to make the range larger than the list because they won't display cells that are null.

Comment: Extremely sorry @Cooper I didn't get you. Which list are you referring to ?

Comment: I guess now that think about I was referring to the use of creating dataValidations with nameRanges.  And there I  tend to use ranges that are larger than I expect to ever need so that I can change the number of item in the drop down list with messing with the named range.