# Google Sheets Script: Insert New Row In Named Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Named Ranges a lot, for sheets Data Validation etc. I'm adding 'Saved Comparisons' (cell H3) to a stock comparison sheet:

[image]

Although untested yet, I've *almost* created a function to Save or Update the current comparison to a Named Range `Compare_Saved`:

[image]

However, I'm stuck at how to add a New Row to the Named Range, and/or then select the required Row in the Range to update it. The problem is described in the indented section of the code below, commented with `// *****` (*may need to scroll down to see it*):

```
function compareSaveNew()     { compareSave('new');    }  // button call
function compareSaveUpdate()  { compareSave('update'); }  // button call

function compareSave(mode){
  const srcSheet  = 'Compare';
  const dataSheet = 'Data';
  const ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sSrc  = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheet);
  const sData = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheet);
  const ui    = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var promptMsg='', data, rv, rUpdate;

  // Check/confirm if adding new, or updating
  if ( mode == 'update' && src.getRange('Compare_SavedUsed') == 'Select Comparison' ) {
      promptMsg = 'A Saved Comparison has not been selected. Cancel, or enter a New Name: ';
  } else if ( mode == 'new' && src.getRange('Compare_SavedUsed') != 'Select Comparison' ) {
      promptMsg = 'A Saved Comparison has been selected. Cancel and use [UPDATE],\nOR\n' +
                  'enter a New Name if you want to Save a new Comparison based on this one: ';
  } else {
      promptMsg = 'New Name for Saved Comparison: ';
  }
  var newName = ui.prompt('New Name for Saved Comparison: ');
  if (!newName) {return;}                                         // Exit, Save/Update cancelled

  // Check newName is unique
  data = sData.getRange('Compare_Saved');
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if( data[i][0] == newName ) { rv = true; break; }
  }
  if (rv) {ui.alert('"' + newName + '" aleady exists.'); return;} // Exit, new name exists

          // ***** 
          // Create New row in Named Range
          if (mode=='new') {
            // add row to range - how ???
          }
          // Get new/existing row as range from Named Range to update
          // var rUpdate = sData.getRange( ??? );
          // ***** 

  var newSave=[];
  newSave.push([
    newName,
    '',               // left blank, so name can overflow to this col in Data sheet
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Period'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Frequency'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_From'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_To'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Index'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Stock1'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Stock2'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Stock3'),
    sSrc.getRange('Compare_Stock4')
    ]);
  rUpdate.setValues(newSave);
  return true;
}
```

Apologies if this post is a bit verbose, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about remove() and addNew() [namedRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range)

Comment: Am working on a previous example of yours at /https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011251/190925 !  Cheers, Max

Answer (score 1):

Adapted code I found by @Cooper (thanks!) for my specific needs, which returns new row num, or row num to be updated, depending on `mode`:

```
function compareAddOrFindRowInNR(namedRange,newName,mode){
// Purpose: Add a new row in Named Range and return row num, OR return existing row num
// Credit:  @Cooper at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011251/190925

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get the NR
  var nrAll = ss.getNamedRanges()
  for (var i=0; i<nrAll.length; i++) {
    if( nrAll[i].getName() == namedRange ) {
      var nr = nrAll[i];
      var h  = nr.getRange().getHeight();       Logger.log('h: '+h)
      var row= nr.getRange().getRow();          Logger.log('row: '+row)
      var w  = nr.getRange().getWidth();        Logger.log('w: '+w)
      var col= nr.getRange().getColumn();       Logger.log('col: '+col)
      var sh = nr.getRange().getSheet();      Logger.log('sh: '+sh)

      // Create new row in NR, or find existing row
      if (mode=='new') {
        var updateNR = sh.getRange(row,col,h+1,w);
        ss.setNamedRange(namedRange,updateNR);      // doesn't set Sheet?
        var rowUpdate = row+h;

      } else {
        data = nr.getRange().getValues();
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          Logger.log(data[i][0]);
          if( data[i][0] == newName ) {
            var rowUpdate = row+i;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log('rowUpdate: '+rowUpdate);
  return rowUpdate;
}
```